# Android GridView with categories?

Tags: android, gridview, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is it possible to use categories or some sort of headers with a `GridView` in Android?

I put together a quick illustration of what I was thinking about:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you eventually solve this problem?

Comment: Hello, i managed to add the categories but they are shown as a grid cell. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: That's just a Gridview instead of a Listview.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same behavior as Victor. By simply using this SeparatedListAdapter on a GridView instead of a ListView, the headers are also constrained by the grid.

Comment: @Michell Bak . Can u plz share some code for doing this. I am stuck here.

Comment: The Best Smaple code is https://github.com/guoGavin/Andorid-StickyHeaderGridView here

Comment: @MichellBak can u pls take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181995/how-to-pass-arraylist-of-objects-to-populate-each-section-heading-text-and-its-c to achive this http://imgur.com/CahCCqI

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Stickygridheaders](http://tonicartos.github.com/StickyGridHeaders/) library directly or as a model to create your own widget.

Comment: That looks pretty sweet. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Just revised this again, and this is actually a much better solution.

Comment: im struggling to do even by looking at both the tutorials.. u guys mind helping me?

Comment: can you help me how to pass data from ArrarList<>

Comment: The project mentions on github that it has been superseeded by https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

Answer (score 3):

probably [this code](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/e81e126227f8a4bb339c) will help you. This is SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter, result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: can you advice how to add click listener to this adapter?

Comment: @AEMLoviji On SimpleAdapter class, on onBindViewHolder method add this: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener

Comment: Thank you @dilettante for your answer. Currently I am not developing mobile apps any more. It was 3 years ago I asked this question. It seems way you have provided  will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think You can do it but you have to implement Jeff Shrkey's [SeparatedListAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

> There isn’t an easy way of creating these separated lists, so I’ve put together SeparatedListAdapter which does it quickly. To summarize, we’re creating a new BaseAdapter that can contain several other Adapters, each with their own section headers.

Comment: How does this have any votes?  The SeperatedListAdapter only seems to apply to ListViews...

Comment: @ingsaurabhi will this work for gridview too with this library https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/

Answer (score 2):

You can modify an Android RecyclerView to return a grids at each row see  [here](https://github.com/koros/GridRecyclerView)

```
Add the `gridrecyclerview` library to your project
```

```yaml
implementation 'com.github.koros:gridrecyclerview:1.0.2'
```

Once the library is added, follow these steps to create a grid view:

#### 1. Implement the GridRecyclerViewHelper

Begin by creating a helper class that implements `GridRecyclerViewHelper`. This class manages the creation of headers, the binding of header data, the setup of grid views, and the creation of grid view holders.

```
public class SampleGridRecyclerViewHelper implements GridRecyclerViewHelper<GridHeader> {
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_view, parent, false);
       return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, GridHeader headerItem) {
       ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).bind(headerItem);
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public ViewGroup getGridView(GridHeader key, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
       switch (key.getKey()) {
           case ACTOR:
               return (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.actor_view, parent, false);
           case GENRE:
               return (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.genre_view, parent, false);
           case MOVIE:
               return (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_view, parent, false);
           case STUDIO:
               return (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.studio_view, parent, false);
           case DIRECTOR:
               return (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.director_view, parent, false);
           default:
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Header Key Value");
       }
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public GridCellViewHolder getGridViewHolder(GridHeader key, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
       switch (key.getKey()) {
           case ACTOR:
               return new ActorViewHolder(parent);
           case GENRE:
               return new GenreViewHolder(parent);
           case MOVIE:
               return new MovieViewHolder(parent);
           case STUDIO:
               return new StudioViewHolder(parent);
           case DIRECTOR:
               return new DirectorViewHolder(parent);
           default:
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Header Key Value");
       }
   }
}
```

The `GridHeader` class serves as a Plain Old Java Object (POJO) holding information about grid section headers.

#### 2. Implement ViewHolder for Each Grid Cell

Next, implement the `GridCellViewHolder` interface to efficiently bind data to each type of grid cell.

```
public abstract class GridCellViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // Implement the bind method to efficiently bind data to the ViewHolder.
}
```

For instance, create a specialized ViewHolder for actor cells:

```
public class ActorViewHolder extends GridCellViewHolder<Actor> {
    private final Context context;
    private final TextView name;
    private final ImageView image;

    public ActorViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.context = itemView.getContext();
        this.name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        this.image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(Actor actor) {
        this.name.setText(actor.getName());
        this.image.setImageDrawable(getDrawableFromName(context, actor.getImage()));
    }
}
```

[image]