# How to show Grouped/Categorized thumbnails in grid/table like layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

This is my first post, so please be considerate of any mistakes or lack of clarity:)

I need to show image thumbnails (in a grid/table like layout) categorized by dates, following is an illustration* of the way it has to be shown.

---

**Date:30 Apr 2012**

*Image1 Image2 Image3*

*Image4 Image5 Image6*

**Date:1st May 2012**

*Image1 Image2 Image3*

*Image4 Image5*

**Date:1st May 2012**

*Image1 Image2*

---

Based on all the looking around that I have done, I haven't found no straight forward way to do it. Following are two possible layouts that come closer, but each has some problems

- **GridView**, don't know how can I add date/group headers in between the content, as column span is not possible.
- **TableLayout**, though columnspan is possible but I am not sure if the desired layout can be achieved. And I read that whenever the orientation changes or app runs on a different devices, the number of rows and columns have to be computed (which is not so in grid). And what I have gathered, in TableLayout extra work needs to be done for cell level events.

An important consideration is that around 4000 thumbnails will be shown.

I have gone through some posts on stackoverflow, but none is talking about the kind of layout listed above, for example the following question is same but the answer is providing grouping in a ListView rather than grid/table like layout

Link: [Android GridView with categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397988/android-gridview-with-categories)

Please provide some ideas. Thanks.

**As I am new user so can not upload images, hence the textual illustration, kindly bear.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scroll view with a linear layout` of orientation to be vertical. Have two separate layout one having the `Textview to be the header text` and other `layout containing three image views`. Just add these two layouts to the scroll view in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two nested layouts for this. You probably want ScrollView for the toplevel and inside this ScrollView a GridView for the images of each category.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [StickyGridHeaders library](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/) will be a good solution. It will help you to make a grid view with 
categories.