# Android - How to make sections in gridview?

Tags: android

I can able to display images in each cell in gridview. now i want to segregate into two section with headers. so that i an define my images to be placed in different sections. can somebody please help me.

Comment: the best sample https://github.com/guoGavin/Andorid-StickyHeaderGridView

Answer (score 7):

It's possible with custom implementation. Try [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) it's very easy to use

Comment: is it possible to add images and two text views i tried but i failed

Comment: how to categories according to our own category.. its is  sectioning according to its first character

Answer (score 3):

This is not strictly possible with a single `GridView`. However, a fairly straightforward approach to visually present a series of grids with headers/categories is to use a separate `GridView` for every section. Basically you'll probably end up using one 'root' adapter that contains each of the adapters for the grid sections.

A good starting point is having a read through the following two similar questions, as they refer to components that already do most the hard work for you (no need to reinvent the wheel):

- [Android GridView with categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397988/android-gridview-with-categories)
- [GridView with section headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203594/gridview-with-section-headers)