# Adding sections to gridview

Tags: android, android-preferences, drawerlayout

***Dear Stackoverflowers,***

I have a `Gridview` i want to add `headers` to. Well i can look at sample and do it. 
Thanks, so `no link` to how to do it, i just want to ask about the concept.

Consider that i want to add `headers` that represent date's like `September 2013, October 2013` , how can i inform the application that `October 2013` comes after `September 2013`?

**Basically** i was thinking to add an `online table` and i fill that table with the `months by order`,

Then add a row to my initial table that the application uses called "`Date`" so if the value of that row match the value of the row that "Months" table it displays in the **section**. And if `none match`, don't show the row. 
Is it a **great concept**? or i can make it more **intuitive** ??

***Please share with me your ideas!***

***Thanks a lot!***

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397988/android-gridview-with-categories