# GridView with date wise separator

Tags: android, gridview, filter, separator

I want to display images in GridView with month wise separator. Can any one please help me for that.

Here I attached screenshot of demo GridView with separator.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably searching something like below

http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/

and may be your question is duplicate of [Android GridView with categories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397988/android-gridview-with-categories)

Answer (score -1):

add the following xml as background to the imageview containing layout in gridview

and similar background to your gridview by adjusting the shape and maintaining tha same colors

`

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:dither="true"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#777777" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="1dp"
      android:right="1dp">
    <shape
        android:dither="true"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#d7d7d7" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

`