# how to pass arraylist of objects to populate each section heading text and its content?

Tags: android, header, android-gridview

I'am using [StickyGridHeaders](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) for GridView with sections.

this library is using `R.array.countries` to populate `GridView` with provided data and extracting first letter from passed string array to create section heading.

I m trying to pass an `ArrayList` of objects  that will contain `ArrayList` for sections text named as `"sectionArrayList"` and `"contentArrayListPrivate"` and `"contentArrayListPublic"`.

Now i want to play a for loop that will play till `< sectionArrayList.size` and will check is there any sections then show section text and then show all contents associated with this section by `contentArrayListPrivate.size` and similar for others but unable to achieve my target.

Can someone please point me towards right direction how to achieve this task ?

want to achive something like:

[image: required image]

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded it and checked to solve your problem. so here is solution.

First of all that project is replaced to SuperSlim it is showing on your given link itself, so get superslim.

Then follow the example in that project to achieve it. In that example there is a file named `CountryNamesAdapter.java` open it, in the 37th line there i found this

```
final String[] countryNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
```

which means the data is loaded from Array resource

replace it with

your data - convert your arraylist to string array and assign it like this

```
final String[] countryNames = myData.
```

Comment: once i m using superslim i m getting output  like this in form of listview instead of gridview while once i m using the same prj i  mentioned link above then i m getting gridview what the reason ? @kashif Anwar

Comment: In SuperSlim project i noted now by default it falls to ListView, there are options for GridView more, check their guide..

Comment: yes there is option but they have not mention how to achive GridView do u have any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: I have solved your problem, Why you didn't accept or vote? Don't be rude please

Comment: u did  not still solve my problem the point u have mentioned here is not my solution i want like this how its working here http://www.programering.com/a/MjN0ITMwATU.html

Comment: you did not told that in question, what you asked in question is solved

Comment: you just asked to use ArrayList data instead of Array resource...dont be rude

Comment: ask another questin for what you want like this how its working here programering.com/a/MjN0ITMwATU.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87782/discussion-between-erum-and-kashif-anwar).